# Knockout: click other place of the page and hide the element

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm creating a 2 level menu, so clicking on the topmenu item , the submenu shows up, if clicking on other places of the page rather than the submenu itself, the submenu should hide. I'm not leaning to adding a click bind to the body tag, it's not going to work anyway, but what can I do to achieve this?
here is my code so far.

```
<div id="menuholder">
<ul id="topmenu">
    <li  data-bind="click: showMenu.bind($data, 1)">top menu item</li>
    <ul class="submenu" data-bind="visible: selected() == '1'">
         <li><a href="#">submenu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var menuModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable(0);
    self.showMenu = function (data) {
        var s = self.selected();
        if (s > 0 && data == s)
            self.selected(0);
        else
            self.selected(data);
    };
    self.hideMenu = function () {
        self.selected(0);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new menuModel(), document.getElementById("menuHolder"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('yourParentDivId').click(function(e) {  
    if (!( $(e.target).is('topmenu') && $(e.target).is('submenu') ) ) {  
        alert('clicked');  
        self.hideMenu();
    }  
});
```

[Refer Here knockout delegate event](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. Works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you check out how [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) does its dropdowns, it adds an event to the `html` element:

Inside Dropdown class definition:

```
...
  $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
      $el.parent().removeClass('open')
  })
```

You could try something similar.